# Syncfusion WPF PdfViewer - any workaround for incorrectly displaying PDFs with semitransparent colors?

Tags: wpf, syncfusion, pdfviewer

Are you aware of any workaround for incorrectly displaying PDFs with semitransparent colors in latest Syncfusion WPF PdfViewer?

I have filed a bug report: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/132687/pdfviewer-incorrectly-display-and-print-pdfs-with-semitransparent-colors , but it will probably take a while to fix it.

[image: Comparision of correct rendering with Syncfusion WPF PdfViewer rendering]

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue in rendering the PDF document in Syncfusion’s PDF viewer. Please contact Syncfusion support using the below link to report this issue.

[Syncfusion support](https://www.syncfusion.com/account/login)

Comment: I have reported issue already : https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/132687/pdfviewer-incorrectly-display-and-print-pdfs-with-semitransparent-colors and issue #187892. But since in our experience so far fixing issues by Syncfusion takes very long I was hoping for some known workaround for now.